# bit-refected constant of PCLMULQDQ fast-crc

Tags: crc

I am confused about how to calculate the bit-reflected constants in the white paper "Fast CRC Computation for Generic Polynomials Using PCLMULQDQ Instruction".

In the post [Fast CRC with PCLMULQDQ *NOT* reflected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328336/fast-crc-with-pclmulqdq-not-reflected) and [How the bit-reflect constant is calculated when we use CLMUL in CRC32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71852080/how-the-bit-reflect-constant-is-calculated-when-we-use-clmul-in-crc32), @rcgldr mentioned that "*...are adjusted to compensate for the shift, so instead of x^(a) mod poly, it's (x^(a-32) mod poly)<<32...*", but I do not understand what does this mean.

For example, constant k1=(x^(4*128+64)%P(x))=0x8833794c (on page 16) v.s. k1'=(x^(4*128+64-32)%P(x)<<32)'=(0x154442db4>>1) (on page 22), I can't see those two figures have any reflection relationship (10001000_00110011_01111001_01001100 v.s 10101010_00100010_00010110_11011010).

I guess my question is why the exponent needs to subtract 32 to compensate 32bits of left shift? and why k1 and (k1)' are not reflected?

Could you please help to interpret it? Thanks

I had carefully searched for the answer to this question on the internet, especially in StackOverflow, and I tried to understand the related posts but need some experts to interpret more.

Answer (score 1):

I modded what was originally some Intel examples to work with Visual Studio | Windows, not-reflected and reflected for 16, 32, and 64 bit CRC, in this github repository.

https://github.com/jeffareid/crc

I added some missing comments and also added a program to generate the constants used in the assembly code for each of the 6 cases.

> instead of x^(a) mod poly, it's (x^(a-32) mod poly)<<32

This is done for non-reflected CRC. The CRC is kept in the upper 32 bits, as well as the constants, so that the result of PCLMULQDQ ends up in the upper 64 bits, and then right shifted. Shifting the constants left 32 bits is the same as multiplying by 2^32, or with polynomial notation, x^32.

For reflected CRC, the CRC is kept in the lower 32 bits, which are logically the upper 32 bits of a reflected number. The issue is PCLMULQDQ multiplies the product by 2, right shifting the product by 1 bit, leaving bit 127 == 0 and the 127 bit product in bits 126 to 0. To compensate for that, the constants are (x^(a) mod poly) << 1   (left shift for reflected number is == divide by 2).

The example code at that github site includes crc32rg.cpp, which is the program to generate the constants used by crc32ra.asm.

---

Another issue occurs when doing 64 bit CRC. For non-reflected CRC, sometimes the constant is 65 bits (for example, if the divisor is 7), but only the lower 64 bits are stored, and the 2^64 bit handled with a few more instructions. For reflected 64 bit CRC, since the constants can't be shifted left, (x^(a-1) mod poly) is used instead.

Comment: Thanks @rcgldr, let me think and back here once I catch your meaning or have further questions.

Comment: @Pengcheng - directy link to [crc32rg.cpp](https://github.com/jeffareid/crc/blob/master/crc32r/crc32rg.cpp), the program that generates the constants used by crc32ra.asm.